# Create unit tests to validate the string[] returned from a solidity function

Tags: solidity, unittesting

I have a solidity function like the one below,

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Funding {
    function sum(uint input1, uint input2) public returns (uint) {
        return input1 + input2;
    }

    struct patient{
        uint id;
        string fullName;
        mapping(uint => string[]) DoctorAccess;        
    }

    function getPatient(uint patientId, uint doctorId) public returns (string[]) {
        patient p;
        p.id = 1;
        p.fullName="Saran";
        p.DoctorAccess[doctorId].push("Doctor1Key");
        return p.DoctorAccess[doctorId];
    }
}
```

The compilation of the code looks good. Hence, i have created a test case for the above one as given below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "../contracts/Funding.sol";

contract FundingTest {

    function testSum() public {
        Funding  f= new Funding();
        Assert.equal(f.sum(1,2),3," two plus one should be three");
    }

    function test_getPatient() public {
        Funding f = new Funding();
        string[] doctorKeys;
        doctorKeys.push("Doctor1Key");
        Assert.equal(f.getPatient(1,1),doctorKeys, "The doctor mapping should be a valid one");
    }
}
```

When I try to run the test case, i am getting the below error

> ,/H/ethereum/PM/test/FundingTest.sol:18:9: TypeError: Member "equal"
>   not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in
>   type(library Assert) Assert.equal(f.getPatient(1,1),doctorKeys, "The
>   doctor mapping should be a valid one");

Is the above test case wrong or is there something that needs to be addressed.

Comment: Similarly, i have created a solidity function that returns the struct, however, i don't find any example that can be used to consume the struct returned from the method within the test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equal Method in solidity's Assert does not support arrays.

As mentioned [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40874/how-to-compare-two-arrays-in-solidity) you would need to create a seperate Assert.equal statement for each entry in the array.